# Is there a way to set the BackColor of Winforms ListView cells individually?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, customization

I want to color each list view cell's BackColor using a different color. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To change the colour of a cell's `BackColor`, you can do this:

```
listView1.Items[0].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
listView1.Items[0].SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Green;
listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Orange;
listView1.Items[0].SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.Red;
// Change the 0 in Items[0] for whatever row you want,
// and the 0, 1 or 2 in SubItems[0] to whatever column you want.
```

The first line,

```
listView1.Items[0].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
```

Will make it so that the row of cells is not all coloured the same colour.

Here is a demo picture:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use this property, then it works:

```
myListView.Items[i].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
```

Comment: I found the answer at the same time that's why I posted it here.