# Listview Subitems back Color

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I can Set Listview Subitem's backcolor to Desired Color Using this code

```
item1.SubItems.Add("Color")
item1.SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.Red
item1.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
```

But is possible to set Subitems backcolor to half red And half Blue or White
If Yes Then How

Like Image [image]

Comment: Half and half in what way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958171/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-backcolor-of-winforms-listview-cells-individually
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268113/way-to-color-parts-of-the-listbox-listview-line-in-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: @Szymon Imean By Example image

Comment: @lomed It's not what i asked

Comment: set OwnerDraw  to true then use DrawItem event. see example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2